# Recreating the functionality of AccountPartner

Tags: apex, trigger

In our org, we have a custom object Relationship and each Relationship ties two Person Accounts together. I am trying to update a custom field UniqueID, which combines both Person Accounts' IDs together, and then update another custom field ReverseID, which is just the Person Accounts IDs, just switched in orders.

An example of a Unique ID would be 001G000001zPkCCAAA001G000001zPkBsAAB which is a combination of two account records. The Reverse ID would be 001G000001zPkBsAAB001G000001zPkCCAAA.

I am trying to accomplish the example above through Apex, but I am getting multiple errors.  Being fairly new to Apex & Triggers, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
    trigger RelationshipReverseRecord on Relationship (before insert, before update, before delete)
{
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        Set<string> rIDs = new Set(string)();
        for(Relationship r : Trigger.New)
        {
            String uID = r.parentID + r.childID;
            String rID = r.childID + parentID;
            r.UniqueID__c = uID;
            r.ReverseID__c = rID;
            rIDs.add(rID);
        }
    }
    List<Relationship__c> existing ReverseRecords = [SELECT UniqueID, Reverse_Record__c FROM Relationship__c WHERE ID IN : rIDs0];
    List<Relationship> new Reverse Records = new List<>();
    for(Relationship__c new R : Trigger.New)
    {
        if(new R.ReverseID__c == existing R.UniqueID__c)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found==false && new R.ReverseRecord)
    {
        Relationship__c new Reverse = new Relationship__c(ReverseRecord__c = true, Parent__c = new R.Child__c);
        new Reverse.Child__c = new R.Parent__c;
        new ReverseRecords.add (new Reverse);
    }
}

insert newReverseRecords;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to actually contain a sentence that is a question. As it stands, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Adrian just updated :)

Comment: Better, but still does not contain a question. What are you *asking*?

Comment: @Sutha - I still don't see a question

Comment: Sorry I am not having the greatest time explaining myself.  Pretty much I am trying to accomplish what is in the example

Comment: @Sutha - Great - Then use what is in the example.....Problem solved. Or try "The code is not doing XYZ instead it is doing ABC" Or "The code is throwing an Error [msg]" or something....any question will be a good start. So far you have provided 1. Requirements and 2. A code Example, we need 3. A question that you need us to answer

Comment: Yes, input/output combos, expected vs. observed behavior, error messages? Any of these might clarify what you are trying to achieve and why the code you have already shared does not do what you need.

Comment: okay, so here's the error I am getting  - Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'ReverseRecords' at line 15 column 35

Answer (score 1):

Seems this

```
List<Relationship> new Reverse Records = new List<>();
```

Should be removed as it is defined on the line above it not to mention it is syntactically incorrect  or change it to

```
 List<Relationship__c> newReverseRecords = new List<Relationship__c>();
```

And

```
 List<Relationship__c> existing ReverseRecords
```

Should be

```
List<Relationship__c> existingReverseRecords
```